# Market making algo using bid ask order volume ladder

Tags: algorithmic-trading, market-making, limit-order-book

I am looking for references for market-making strategies using bid-ask order ladder. Algo should suggest entry prices, and do inventory management. I am more interested in practical simple algo used commonly in the industry.